# Understanding Pandas grouby sum()

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am unable to understand how sum() works in case of groupby(). [Official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum) say it computes sum of values but I can't see how:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
               'B': [np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 5],
               'C': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2]},
               columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

[image]

I don't see how it computed the result, it definitely didn't do A+B+C for every row.

Comment: `df = df.groupby('A').sum()`

Comment: I think you grouping by B, but you want A

Comment: I want neither. I want to know how it does its sum(). The method.

Comment: I think you are missing what [groupy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) does, not the `sum()`. Are you looking for `df.sum(axis='columns')`?

Comment: Yeah, after reading  the answer from @Boendal, I think you are correct on I can't grasp what groupby() does

Answer (score 1):

Your example is quite bad but let me explain.

Groupby is an operation that takes the value of the column and merge all equal values together. Now we need an operation to deal with the other columns. Because with the merging the program needs to know how to deal with them. And that would be the operation sum. (Other Operations: mean, count, ...)

In your case you only have unique value in `B` and therefore there are no 2 rows that are merging together. Therefore what is the sum of one element? exactly the element.

```
l = [3]
print(sum(l)) # Output: 3
```

And that is what is happening in your example.

That is why [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59929165/understanding-pandas-grouby-sum#comment105980409_59929165) said in the comment you probably want to do `df = df.groupby('A').sum()`

The output would be:

```
     B  C
A        
1  6.0  4
2  8.0  3
```

As you see we group by column A. Row 1 and 3 are added together and Row 2 and 4.

You are maybe looking for this:

```
df.sum()
```

which output:

```
A     7.0
B    14.0
C     7.0
```

Or this mentioned by [@Andrea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59929165/understanding-pandas-grouby-sum/59929657#comment105981095_59929165):

```
df.sum(axis=1)
```

which outputs:

```
0    2.0
1    5.0
2    6.0
3    6.0
4    9.0
```

But Groupby is the wrong way to achieve what you want I think.

Comment: I think you are right about "pretty bad example". Example is taken from offical docs. But then again I see most examples are confusing there.

Answer (score 0):

This can be well understood by comparing the following 2 dataframes :-

Let the dataframe be

[image: original_dataframe]

Doing `df.groupby('B').sum()` gives

[image: groupbyB]

while, doing `df.groupby('A').sum()` gives

[image: groupbyA]

So, what groupby().sum() does is, it takes an element of B, adds the corresponding row element in A and C, and then searches for repetition of that element in column B. If found, it again adds the corresponding value of A and C. If not found, it skips to the next element in column B. To explain further, in the above example, first B = 2.0 is taken, for which A = 1 and C = 2. Since 2.0 is not repeated in column B, it now moves on to B = 3.0, for which A = 2 and C = 1, and so on. This is the output for groupby('B').sum(). On the other hand, when df.groupby('A') is done, it takes A = 1 first. For this, the corresponding values are B = NaN, C = 1. Since 1 repeats in column A, sumB = NaN + 2.0 + 4.0 = 6, sumC = 1 + 2 + 1 = 4. Now that all the values for A = 1 are done, it goes to A = 2. Again, for A = 2, sumB = 3.0 + 5.0 = 8, and sumC = 1 + 2 = 3. This explains the output when groupby('A') was done.

For your problem, `df.sum()` will give the sum of all 3 columns as

```
A   7.0
B   14.0
C   7.0
```

If you want row-wise sum, do `df.sum(axis = 1)`
This will give

```
0   2.0
1   5.0
2   6.0
3   6.0
4   9.0
```